# Postgis - What type to use for any geometry object

Tags: laravel, leaflet, gis, postgis, geojson

I'm trying to use some postgis functions inside a Laravel project to store some geographical information.

With Leaflet and its leaflet-draw plugin, a user can spot on a map the location of an archeological site. But the thing is he can either locate it as a point, if it's a small and precisely located site, or within a polygon that he draws on a map if it's larger or not precise. The layers drawn on a map give me a geojson that I want to transform with Postgis to a geometry object.

So I needed, for my "posha_sites" table, a geometry type that can store anyhting and it seemed to me that the GeometryCollection type was made for this, so here is the up function of my migration when I added my geometry column to my table.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('posha_sites', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->geometrycollection('geometry');
    });
}
```

At first I tried to use njbarrett/laravel-postgis package that I found on GitHub, but I had a SRID problem when trying to insert add GeometryCollection.

```
$site->geometry = new GeometryCollection([new Point(-48.23456, 20.12345)]);
```

Which gave me this error:

```
Invalid parameter value: 7 ERREUR: Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (4326)
```

I don't know if the package offers a way to specify the SRID, so I then just tried a raw sql query using postgis functions:

```
update posha_sites set geometry = ST_SetSRID(ST_ASTEXT(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(\'{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-48.23456,20.12345]}\')), 4326)
```

This way the SRID is set but I still get an error:

```
Invalid parameter value: 7 ERREUR: Geometry type (Point) does not match column type (GeometryCollection)
```

What should I insert so that it matches the GeometryCollection type or should I use another type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your error message...

> ```
> Geometry type (Point) does not match column type (GeometryCollection)
> ```

...it seems that your PostGIS column is a `GeometryCollection` but your data is a `Point`. And indeed, you're providing a [GeoJSON `Point` geometry](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#appendix-A.1) to PostGIS here:

> ```
> ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(\'{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-48.23456,20.12345]}\')
> ```

The approach here would be to wrap that GeoJSON `Point` geometry into a [GeoJSON `GeometryCollection` geometry](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#appendix-A.7), e.g.:

```
ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(\'{"type":"GeometryCollection", "geometries": [{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-48.23456,20.12345]}]}\')
```

Note that a `GeometryCollection` can have zero, one or more geometries. The GeoJSON representation of a `GeometryCollection` includes an array (i.e. `[]`, `[{...}, {...}]`) of geometries - the brackets surrounding the point denote it's an array of one geometry.

Another approach (depending on your requirements) would be to change the PostGIS column type from `GeometryCollection` to `Geometry` (or `Geography` depending on the importance of geodesy in your scenario). A `Geometry` PostGIS field can hold `Points`, `LineString`s, `Polygon`s or `MultiGeometry`s; whereas a `MultiGeometry` field can only hold a `MultiGeometry` value (and inside that value you can pack other geometry types).

If the last paragraph was confusing, I suggest you become acquainted with the [Simple Features Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Features), which explains the relationships between different geometry types.

---

Addendum: relevant PostGIS documentation about column types is at https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html

Comment: Well, indeed, geometry type is what I was looking for instead of geometry collection. Thank you. I remember that I already tried the geometry type but that DBAL was throwing an error when I was trying to migrate. Here it works but I don't what I did to make it work.